# How to insert a sample of text in a new document in the same command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i try this to put a text sample into a new document create in the same command.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as fs from 'fs'; 
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable_getSelectedFolder = vscode.commands.registerCommand('tima.getSelectedFolder', (uri:vscode.Uri) => {
            let selectedPath = uri.fsPath;
            let fileNameBase; 
            if(selectedPath){
                const wsedit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
                fileNameBase = LastSubFolder(selectedPath);
                wsedit.createFile(vscode.Uri.file(selectedPath+"\\"+fileNameBase+".cpp"),{ignoreIfExists:false} );
                wsedit.createFile(vscode.Uri.file(selectedPath+"\\"+fileNameBase+".h"),{ignoreIfExists:false} );
                vscode.workspace.applyEdit(wsedit);
            }else{
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage("selectedPath n'a pas été défini");
                return;  //TODO: Voir pour enregistrer un defaut à un endroit approprié.
            }       
            //Write in source and header file
            let sourceFile;
            let textToSource = "#include <"+fileNameBase+".h>";         // The text to send in sourceFile.cpp
            let fileToOpen = selectedPath+"\\"+fileNameBase+".cpp";

            function LastSubFolder(words:String) {
                var n = words.split("\\");
                return n[n.length - 1];         
            }           
            if (!fs.existsSync(fileToOpen)) {
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`le fichier n'existe pas`);
            }

            function writeInFile(file:String,text:string){
                vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(fileToOpen).then((sourceFile: vscode.TextDocument) => {
                    vscode.window.showTextDocument(sourceFile ,1,false).then(e => {
                        e.edit(edit =>{
                            edit.insert(new vscode.Position(0,0),textToSource);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
```

The files have been created, but the text hasn't been inserted.
It's because the file has not yet been created when the send text command is executed.
How can i resolve this  please?

Answer (score 0):

To resolved this, i used the callback of `vscode.workspace.onDidCreateFiles`:

```
const wsedit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();              
                wsedit.createFile(vscode.Uri.file(selectedPath+"\\"+fileNameBase+".cpp"),{ignoreIfExists:false} );
                wsedit.createFile(vscode.Uri.file(selectedPath+"\\"+fileNameBase+".h"),{ignoreIfExists:false} );
                vscode.workspace.applyEdit(wsedit);
                vscode.workspace.onDidCreateFiles(()=> {
                    vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Les fichiers sont en cours de création");
                    headerText(fileNameBase);
                });
```

Comment: What happens if you use **File** | **New** ?

Comment: I don't know this way, I'm totally beginner's in TS and JS... Can you send me an exemple please?